# Not all events appear in Nagios history (archive)

Tags: nagios, archive, check-mk

In the **Host & Service history** of my `check_mk` interface I can see various events, but a lot of events are missing. On the default interface at **View Alert History For This Service** or in the logfiles `/var/log/nagios/archives/*.log` the same issue: I can see many events of the last days, but not all of them.

In the `/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg` the options `log_event_handlers`, `log_initial_status` and `log_passive_checks` are set to `0`. The other `log_...` options are set to `1`.

I don't think that any of these options causing the problem that not all events are logged.

What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Nagios will typically not store successive 'OK' results.  Are you missing those 'OK's, or something a bit more colorful?